# set twig variable from json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

As twig renders prior to any javascript, I'm running into what feels like a minor problem.

I need to set a variable in twig that I receive from JSON array, but I'm running into some problems, and I feel like this should be simple.

The data is fed to twig through symfony through a json array, and renders different messages depending on one element in the array;  this part works without trouble.

I am able to print the output to the twig file;  that works fine.  The problem is that I'm having a hard time setting this to a twig variable so that I can use it in a few places.

This works fine:

`$('.id').html(items[0].id);`

and prints out to the twig here correctly:

`<div class="id"></div>`

I tried to do do something like this:

```
{% set requestid = '<div class="id"></div>' %}
{{ requestid }}
```

But as expected this simply rendered the HTML without the value.

I've been attempting to do something like this:

In the twig I have this:

```
{% set requestid = "request_holder" %}
{{ requestid }}
```

And in the jquery I have something like this:

```
var reqid = items[0].id;
reqid.replace("request_holder",reqid);
```

I also attempted something like this

```
var request_id = items[0].id;
window.location = request_id.replace("request_holder",request_id)
```

I feel like I'm missing a small piece.

**Edit for clarity **

The JSON array is being parsed by jquery.

I have the value of `items[0].id`

*Additional edit here - to make it clear that I was confused:  cleaning up a little so as not to send future readers down the wrong path*

I believe[d] that the variable needs to be assigned in the javascript because the twig, which is php, is generated prior to the javascript.

I have been attempting to generate the twig in the javascript to no avail.

Here's what I have been attempting:

```
var requestitem = items[0].id;
$('.id').html("{% set requestId = " + requestitem + " %} <br/> {{ requestId }}");
```

This defines requestId as a string and is only returning `+ requestitem +` onto the page.

When I attempt this (without the quotations)

```
var requestitem = items[0].id;
$('.id').html("{% set requestId = requestitem %} <br/> {{ requestId }}");
```

The twig does not recognize `requestitem` at all

I have attempted quoting out the twig brackets (e.g. `"{" + "%"` etc) but this of course only prints them onto the page and does not interpret them.

Comment: Good effort at pointing out this many cases in such a clear way. This effort should be more appreciated among the community , and having only 3 votes seems so low...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from ASOlivieri,  I was able to realize what I was doing wrong.  I'm putting this here in case anyone comes across this.  I was simply looking for a way to create a variable and make it reusable (I didn't go into details as that seemed extraneous).

The data was only available in the JSON array, so any attempt to write it to a twig file would fail, quite simply because it had already been converted to HTML, so I was forced to find another solution,

I was able to keep the variable in a javascript as I had it before

```
var request_item = items[0].id;
```

As my original goal was to get the value to update the application through php, I simply needed to use this variable in an AJAX call, and pass it through the path I had wanted to use in twig.  Here's a brief summary:

```
$('#mark-received').click(function()
   {
      var requestURL = "{{ path('my_path') }}";
      jQuery.ajax({
          url: requestURL,
          type: 'GET',
          data: {'id' : request_item},
          success: function success(data, text, xhr){
              $('#mark-received').addClass('hidden');
              $('#received-canceled').removeClass('hidden');
              $('header > .alerts').append( $('<div>Success Message</div>').addClass('alert alert-success'));
          },
          error: function error( xhr, status, err){
             $('header > .alerts').append( $('<div>There is a problem. <div class="close">x</div></div>', err).addClass('alert alert-danger'));
           }
       })
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Twig processes on the server side. It takes variables and renders them as HTML and text. What gets displayed in the browser is just HTML / text / and Javascript. So your `set requestid = "request_holder"` and `{{ requestid}}` are just turned to text before they get to the browser.

After that, you have HTML and text on the front end which Javascript can interact with. If you need this id to change on the front end, it needs to be done in Javascript.

What are you using the id to do?

Comment: This was exactly my question.  The problem is that the php renders first before the javascript.  I need to be able to convert the id pulled through the JSON array, and convert it into a variable using javascript (or jquery) that I can use in the twig file.  My end goal is to pass it through a specific path, however I'd like to be able to use it in other methods as well;  if I can convert this into a twig variable that would be ideal.

Comment: You can't dynamically set a twig variable with Javascript. You'll have to get your id via Javascript and call the route via AJAX.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you mean?  I edited the question to clarify

Comment: "I fully understand that the variable needs to be assigned in the javascript because the twig, which is php, is generated prior to the javascript." NO. The "twig" functionality isn't even there. It doesn't exist by the time Javascript is run. If you need a Javascript variable, such as from your JSON array, then you need to handle it strictly in Javascript. Twig is nowhere to be seen on this end. If you need the variable on the server-side you need to pass it to the server via AJAX. That is a different question.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.  time to loop back to the drawing board